# Is it possible that adding a LIMIT to my query is making it slower?

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I have a table with +2.000.000 rows, if I do something like:

```
SELECT 
    *
  FROM transaction 
  WHERE company = 123
  AND date > CURDATE()
  AND name = 4;
```

It takes 120ms, but if I add a LIMIT:

```
SELECT 
    *
  FROM transaction 
  WHERE company = 123
  AND date > CURDATE()
  AND name = 4 
LIMIT 100;
```

It takes 350ms, even if it returns one row.
Shouldn't be the other way around?

Any thoughts?

Comment: show output `explain select...` for both, and output from `show create table transaction`.  are you sure you aren't doing an order by?

Comment: Incidentally, LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless. And never use evil `SELECT *`

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4974657/10910692 .. you might find some insight

Comment: @ysth No ORDER BY, although if I add ORDER BY it takes the same as using only LIMIT

Comment: @Strawberry Adding ORDER BY doesn't improve speed in this case neither do replacing SELECT * with SELECT id =/

Comment: @tcadidot0 thanks looks interesting

Comment: show output of `explain select...` for both queries, and output from `show create table transaction`.  this is essential information if you want help with query optimization

Answer (score 0):

`EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and/or `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` may help explain the difference.  Also `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  With those, I may have more specifics to impart.

Meanwhile, `INDEX(company, name, date)` should help performance.

Adding `ORDER BY date` together with that index will probably run no slower.  Any other `ORDER BY` will possibly necessitate a sort, thereby making the query slow.