# GORM paginate and order issue

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

i want order by id DESC and paginate query use GORM(mysql).

```
var result []User
page := 1
size := 3
offset := (page - 1) * size
if err := conn.Limit(size).Offset(offset).Order("id DESC").Find(&result).Error;err != nil {
    log.Panicf(err)
}
fmt.Println(result)
```

my table have 15 records.

the result return likes [15,14,13] not [3,2,1]
Means sort first and then paginate,how to fix

Comment: How you solved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4974657/7833624. ORDER BY is executed first by sql engine before LIMIT.